# XOpenDisplay returns NULL with pkexec

Tags: x11, polkit

I'm developing simple X app, which works fine with `sudo`, but I can't open display with `pkexec` (`XOpenDisplay` returns 0). Any idea?? What am I missing?

Please note I added following policy in `/usr/local/share/polkit-1/actions` with symlink to `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>

  <action id="com.ubuntu.pkexec.app">
    <description>Test App</description>
    <message>Authentication is required to run Test App</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>no</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/local/bin/app</annotate>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">TRUE</annotate>
  </action>

</policyconfig>
```

Comment: Have you a rule file for this action ?

Comment: Which display name do you pass to `XOpenDisplay()`? `NULL`? Then check if the `DISPLAY` environment variable is valid. Also check if the program has access to `$HOME/.Xauthority` (and check if the `HOME` variable contains the correct value).